# Xcode 7.1 on OSX El Capitan, iOS 7 simulator - is it supposed to work?

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode7, xcode7.1

Xcode 7.1 on OSX El Capitan, iOS 7 simulator - is it supposed to work out of the box?

Just to be sure, I've deleted and re-installed Xcode 7.1 from app store and I don't see ability to install iOS 7.1 simulator from Settings -> Downloads.

Also tried Xcode 6.4 - does not work due to lack of swift 2 support.

Any way I can support iOS 7 for my app?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 does not ship with or support any iOS 7 Simulators, but it does support iOS 7.0 as a deployment target.

Comment: Any reference to Apple's note/announcement on that? 
Any way around that?

Comment: There are some workarounds in [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17108) but they require Xcode 6 to also be installed.